# Using while loop with MouseEnter

Tags: c#

I'm having issues on programming a button that increments when the cursor of the user is over it.

I'm using `MouseEnter` on an image, it calls the following method:

```
private void add_Number(object sender, MouseEventArgs)
{
        _isMouseOver = true;
        while(_isMouseOver)
        {
                i++;
                Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
}
```

The variable that I use as global `_isMouseOver` is simply a `private Boolean` that is initialized at `false`. Also `i` is just a global variable that is set to 0 in the beggining.

To add another call from the image, I use aswell `MouseLeave` that calls another method `sub_Number` that decreases the variable `i` and that puts `_isMouseOver` at false.

The problem is that once we get into the `while` loop, we never get out of there even if a place the cursor outside of the image. When I place it out of the image, it should call the method `sub_Number` to break the execution of the `while` loop and therefore, stop increasing `i` to decrease it.

Do I need to do some multi-threding ? Isn't it going to be more complex that it should ?
Is it bad to use these global variables ?

Comment: input Application.DoEvents() inside of while loop. I think it'll solve that problem.

Comment: Seems like it uses 100% of the CPU, I'm not sure that this is the best thing to do for just an increment.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your goal, the easiest path forward would be to use a Timer control, set to `Enabled = false` on startup.  On MouseEnter, set your boolean as you already do, but also set `Timer.Enabled = true`.  Within the Timer's Tick method, increment and output i.  You can set the interval at design time.  Finally, unset your boolean and set `Timer.Enabled = false` in OnMouseExit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can use multiple timers.

Comment: So I'm doing what you are saying and it looks that it's a good idea but I have a problem. When I use `Timer.Tick` to call my method it says that the method Tick is not in the `System.Timers` package.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Perhaps it would be worth looking into how to work with timers online, and maybe asking a new question if you get stuck.

Comment: Didn't really answered my question but definetely helped me. Here is your upvote.